# Magento - all cart related queries in magento gives internal server error

Tags: magento

I am doing read write operations for fetching the details from cart, adding products into cart and removing products from cart but it's giving error as Internal server error.

Operations those I am doing are in the sales/quote model and once quote object is received, trying to fetch the collection for the same..

$quote->getItemCollection() is the line which is causing a problem.

Earlier same code was giving me results but now its has started giving Internal server error

Comment: try to clear browser cache and try again.

Comment: you should use $cart->getAllItems() instead of $quote->getItemCollection() to get all items in the cart for the session, most probably the erro you are getting is due to the shopping cart rules defined.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Error it gives as Internal server error...

Comment: Share your code, what you have try for this.